# How to use Concurrency control in spring security 3.1 with FilterChainProxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am trying to implement concurrency control with spring security3.1 but it is not working.I am using FilterChainProxy so I don't know how to use concurrency control in it.The code I have tried are below what I am missing please help me out?

Bean file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        ">

        <!--    Custom code by rajesh -->
        <!-- =================================================================== -->

        <!-- Create sessionRegistry Implementation Bean -->
        <bean id="sessionRegistry"  class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

        <bean name="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
          <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
          <property name="expiredUrl" value="/modules/my/login.do"/>
        </bean>



        <bean id="sas" class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.filter.MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
            <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
            <property name="securityImpl" ref="SecurityImpl"/>
        </bean>
        <!-- =================================================================== -->
        <!--     Custom code ended by rajesh -->


        <!-- Create ISecurity Implementation Bean -->
        <bean id="SecurityImpl" class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityImpl">
            <property name="dao">
                <bean class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityDAO">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="sessionRegistry"  ref="sessionRegistry" />
            <property name="persistentRememberMeTokenRepositoryImpl" >
                <bean
                    class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.security.persisted.tokens.PersistentRememberMeTokenRepositoryImpl">
                    <property name="dao">
                        <bean
                            class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.security.persisted.tokens.PersistentRememberMeTokenDAO">
                            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

     <bean id="ISecurityImpl"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager" />
            <property name="target" ref="SecurityImpl" />
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="false" />
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="set*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="checkPasswordExpiry">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="expireSessionBySessionId">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="myFilterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
            <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant" >
                <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" 
                    filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,concurrencyFilter, logoutFilter, usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, rememberMeAuthenticationFilter, passwordExpiryFilter , anonymousAuthenticationFilter, accountExpiryFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, filterSecurityInterceptor" />
            </security:filter-chain-map>
        </bean>
        <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />

        <bean id="logoutFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
            <!-- the post-logout destination -->
            <constructor-arg value="/modules/my/login.do" />
            <constructor-arg>
                <array>
                    <ref bean="myRememberMeService"/>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
                </array>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout_my" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager" />
            <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="myRememberMeService" />
            <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/my_authentication_service"></property>
            <property name="usernameParameter" value="loginid" />
            <property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
            <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="AuthenticationFailureHandler" />
            <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="accountExpiryFilter" class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.filter.MyAccountExpiryFilter">
            <property name="securityImpl" ref="SecurityImpl"/>
            <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="AuthenticationFailureHandler" />
            <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="passwordExpiryFilter"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.filter.MyPasswordExpiryFilter">
            <property name="securityImpl" ref="SecurityImpl"/>
            <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="AuthenticationFailureHandler" />
            <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl">
            <property name="dao">
                <bean class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityDAO">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/modules/my/login.do?error=1" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="AuthenticationFailureHandler"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager" />
            <property name="target" ref="AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl" />
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="onAuthenticationFailure">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.AuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="dao">
                <bean class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityDAO">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="redirect-to"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager" />
            <property name="target" ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl" />
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="onAuthenticationSuccess">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationFilter"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.filter.MyRememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="myRememberMeService" />
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager" />
            <property name="securityImpl" ref="SecurityImpl"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
            <property name="key" value="XXXXXXXX" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
            <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
                    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/modules/my/login.do" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="AccessDeniedHandler" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
            <property name="dao">
                <bean class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityDAO">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="errorPage" value="/modules/errors/accessDenied.do" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="AccessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager" />
            <property name="target" ref="AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" />
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="handle">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


        <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager" />
            <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="myAffirmativeBasedAccessDecisionManager" />
            <property name="securityMetadataSource">
                <security:filter-security-metadata-source
                    use-expressions="true" lowercase-comparisons="true">
                    <!-- Core Actions -->
                    <security:intercept-url pattern="/modules/my/login.do"
                        access="permitAll" />
                    <security:intercept-url pattern="/modules/my/credentialExpired.do"
                        access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
                    <security:intercept-url pattern="/modules/my/*"
                        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
                </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased"
            id="myAffirmativeBasedAccessDecisionManager">
            <property name="decisionVoters">
                <list>
                    <bean id="webExpressionVoter"
                        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                        <property name="expressionHandler" ref="MyWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="MyWebSecurityExpressionHandler"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.spring.web.MyWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
            <property name="iSecurity" ref="SecurityImpl" />
            <property name="roleHierarchy">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
                    <property name="hierarchy">
                        <value>
                            ROLE_MY > ROLE_ADMIN
                            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
                            ROLE_USER > ROLE_PORTAL_USER
                            ROLE_PORTAL_USER > ROLE_GUEST
                            ROLE_GUEST > ROLE_ANONYMOUS
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>


        <bean id="myAuthenticationManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <property name="authenticationEventPublisher" ref="myAuthEventPublisher" />
            <property name="providers">
                <list>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService" />
                        <property name="passwordEncoder">
                            <bean id="myPasswordEncoder"
                                class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.spring.MyPasswordEncoder">
                                <property name="passwordEncryptor" ref="myPasswordEncryptor"></property>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider ">
                        <property name="key" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
                    </bean>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
                        <property name="key" value="MY_SECURE_REMME_MY_APP" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.users.UserImpl">
            <property name="dao" ref="userDao" />
            <property name="passwordEncryptor" ref="myPasswordEncryptor" />
        </bean>

        <!-- like for example at new user sign-up. -->

        <bean id="myRememberMeService"
            class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.DefaultMyRememberMeServices">
            <property name="tokenRepository">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
                    <property name="transactionManager" ref="myTransactionManager" />
                    <property name="target">
                        <bean
                            class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.security.persisted.tokens.PersistentRememberMeTokenRepositoryImpl">
                            <property name="dao">
                                <bean
                                    class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.security.persisted.tokens.PersistentRememberMeTokenDAO">
                                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                                </bean>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="false" />
                    <property name="transactionAttributes">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService" />
            <property name="key" value="MY_SECURE_REMME_MY_APP" />
            <property name="alwaysRemember" value="false" />
            <property name="useSecureCookie" value="true" />
            <property name="cookieName" value="MY_SECURE_REMME" />
            <property name="parameter" value="MY_REMME" />
            <property name="dao">
                <bean class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.impl.SecurityDAO">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="myPasswordEncryptor" class="com.xxxx.xxx.security.spring.MyPasswordEncryptor" />

        <bean id="myAuthEventPublisher"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher" />
        <bean id="authenticationListener"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />
        <bean id="authorizationListener"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener" />

        <bean id="DatabaseConfigImpl" class="com.xxxx.xxx.impl.core.database.config.DatabaseConfigImpl"></bean>
        <bean id="IDatabaseConfig" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="target" ref="DatabaseConfigImpl" />
            <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="false"/>
            <property name="transactionAttributes">
                <props>
                    <prop key="add*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                    <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

In this MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy class extends ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy class with custom implementation.I am also using Custom filter.I have also added HttpSessionEventPublisher in web.xml

My application is working.I am not getting how to apply concurrency control.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown the configuration for the `usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, my first guess would be that you have forgotten to add the necessary hook there by injecting the `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` into that bean. Before adding your own custom versions of classes, you should show that you can get it working with the standard classes. There is an example configuration in [the reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions). Begin from there, make sure that works, and then try adding your `MyConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`. Without seeing the code for that class it could easily be something in there that is wrong.

Also, if you're trying to describe a problem, you should explain in detail what "isn't working", even if it's just that the feature doesn't seem to be enabled when you think it should be. The debug log is also a useful source of information.